# HttpClient has no definition for GetJsonAsync

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently tapping into Blazor, and want to move my code so it's more readable and reusable. In my razor component, the Method works flawlessly - in a Class, it doesn't.

In my component, I can simply use this:

```cs
response = await Http.GetJsonAsync<T>(Uri);
```

In my Class, Visual Studio complains that System.Net.Http's HttpClient contains no definition for GetJsonAsync - but I'm getting a typed response, so I want to deserialize it properly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Great question.  And I'm assuming Darrell's answer (and the others) was 100% correct as of version 3.0.0 (Blazor WebAssembly preview).*

**However, as for version 3.1.301 I think the package location has changed.**

Currently, the namespace is: `System.Net.Http.Json`

That will give you access to: `HttpClientJsonExtensions`

A. If you want to put that code into a separate class within your Blazor WebAssembly project, all you need is to put this at the top of your class file:

```
using System.Net.Http; // for HttpClient
using System.Net.Http.Json; // for HttpClientJsonExtensions
```

B. If you want to put that class into a separate project (.NET Core library) then you need to add the NuGet package also:

NuGet package: `System.Net.Http.Json`

Then you can use it in your class like in the example below.  Obviously these extension methods are doing serialization, but what's interesting is that the package doesn't depend on `Newtonsoft.Json` because it uses the new `System.Text.Json` instead.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public async Task MyMethod()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:57012/";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
            var myPocos = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<MyPoco[]>("api/mypocos");

            foreach (var myPoco in myPocos)
                Console.WriteLine($"Id: {myPoco.Id}, Name: {myPoco.Name}");
        }
    }

    public class MyPoco
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- Article about [System.text.json VS Newtonsoft.json](https://medium.com/@samichkhachkhi/system-text-json-vs-newtonsoft-json-d01935068143) versus Utf8Json.

Comment: If you edit other people's question make sure you don't introduce compile bugs and break the grammar. Or dead code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did you actually compile the code?  Let me help you with that: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0bajky

Comment: TLDR: add `using System.Net.Http.Json;` and dont forget to change `GetJsonAsync` to `GetFromJsonAsync`.

Answer (score 24):

As of preview 8, you need:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" PrivateAssets="all" />`

NOTE: This was correct at the time, but as of Blazor version 3.1.0 this may have changed again so that now you most likely want the `System.Net.Http.Json` package. See the answer from @JohnB below.

Comment: The command might help to install it directly from package manager ----                             Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient -Prerelease

Answer (score 10):

As of today the correct answer is:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json
```

and

```
GetFromJsonAsync()
```

Answer (score 4):

Just download Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient package.

Comment: As of 6/20 the HTTPClient is still in prerelease, so please use this command this command to install this client --> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient -Prerelease

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that "include prerelease" must be checked in order to find this package.  I just spent a half hour getting fairly angry that the package wasn't found and scouring google to find out why!

Comment: I have done this more times than I would like to admit

Answer (score 3):

For Blazor, there is an extension class (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClientJsonExtensions) available to get you the same extension methods.

Ref: https://learn-blazor.com/architecture/rest-api/

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I don't see how your first remark on `MessageHandler` is relevant to the question, you could put it as a side-note perhaps.

Comment: @Tewr, you are right I got carried away thinking about something else.